# How to load dictionary into an nparray in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hello I am trying to load 4x4 matrix into an np array from a dictionary,

```
u'{"column0":{"x":1,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":-1.0},
   "column1":{"x":0.0,"y":1,"z":0.0,"w":-1.0},
   "column2":{"x":1,"y":1,"z":1.0,"w":-1.0},
   "column3":{"x":-1.0,"y":-1.0,"z":-1.0,"w":-1.0}
  }'
```

I want to load it as

```
array([[ 1,0., 0.,-1 ],
       [ 0.,1,0.,-1 ],
       [ 1,1,1,-1 ],
       [ -1,-1,-1,-1 ]])
```

Currently I am looping over each element and I am sure there is a better pythonic way with pandas or numpy directly. Any suggestion?

Comment: `literal_eval`, then change dict to array.

Comment: that would still give me all the headers like coulmn0, x, y ...  etc

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a).as_matrix()`

Comment: this worked but the columns and row values order is being messed up

Comment: This is your really your own fault, `w` is before `x`... Add this `np.roll(mat, -1, axis=0).T`

Comment: careful with dictionary ordering though https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via `numpy` or `pandas`. Both methods require `ast.literal_eval`.

Since dictionaries are unordered, each method will require care to ensure columns are ordered as you require.

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

mystr = """{"column0":{"x":1,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":-1.0},
   "column1":{"x":0.0,"y":1,"z":0.0,"w":-1.0},
   "column2":{"x":1,"y":1,"z":1.0,"w":-1.0},
   "column3":{"x":-1.0,"y":-1.0,"z":-1.0,"w":-1.0}
  }"""

d = literal_eval(mystr)
```

**Option 1: numpy**

```
res_np = np.array([[v[j] for j in ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']] for k, v in d.items()])

# array([[ 1.,  0.,  0., -1.],
#        [ 0.,  1.,  0., -1.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1., -1.],
#        [-1., -1., -1., -1.]])
```

**Option 2: pandas**

```
res_df = pd.DataFrame(d).T.iloc[:, [1, 2, 3, 0]].values

# array([[ 1.,  0.,  0., -1.],
#        [ 0.,  1.,  0., -1.],
#        [ 1.,  1.,  1., -1.],
#        [-1., -1., -1., -1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate your dictionary string using `ast.literal_eval`, put that into a `pandas` transposed dataframe (with `x`, `y`, `z`, `w` as your columns, in that order), and use `as_matrix`:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = u'''{"column0":{"x":1,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":-1.0},
   "column1":{"x":0.0,"y":1,"z":0.0,"w":-1.0},
   "column2":{"x":1,"y":1,"z":1.0,"w":-1.0},
   "column3":{"x":-1.0,"y":-1.0,"z":-1.0,"w":-1.0}
  }'''


df=pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(s))

mat = df.T[['x','y','z','w']].as_matrix()

>>> mat
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0., -1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0., -1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1., -1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1.]])
```